# How to set Value Axis Label Format on QML from milliseconds to mm:ss?

Tags: c++, qt, charts, qml, qt-creator

**Background**

I am using QtCreator and I have a file called *myScopeView.qml*, which represents a scope view similar to the example provided [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-qmloscilloscope-qml-qmloscilloscope-scopeview-qml.html).

In *myScopeView.qml*, there is a ChartView that is updated every second with a timer so the plot changes values on X axis and Y axis.

X axis represents time expressed in milliseconds (integer values), because of the data acquisition, and Y axis represents voltage values (characterized as integer values).

**Problem**

The plot shows X axis values as integer, i.e. 123456789, but I would like to visualize the corresponding **mm:ss** value, i.e. 20:34. I think I have to modify the value of **labelFormat**.

```
    ValueAxis{
        id: axisX
        min: 0
        max: 0
        tickCount: 5
        labelFormat: // I don't know what I have to set here
        }
```

**Question**

Is it possible to set a specific value in **labelFormat** in order to have **mm:ss** visualized?

**Notes**

Instead of the modification of labelFormat I tried to use a Javascript function for the conversion but this solution does not work because the conversion is achieved before the visualization and so the plot shows nothing because there is no Y values associated to new X values. That's why I am asking for a labelFormat command, but I will appreciate also a Javascript hint.

I know that QML QtCharts has QDateTimeAxis which provides **mm:ss** format but I would like to convert data only for the visualization and not for other purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I do this:

```
DateTimeAxis {
            id: axisXw
            min: new Date(appWin.minMsec)
            max: new Date(appWin.maxMsec)
            format: "hh:mm"
            tickCount: 5
            labelsFont:Qt.font({pointSize: 10})
            labelsColor: appWin.baseFontColor
            color: appWin.graphTickColor
        }
```